# Как называется редактор, который используется при создании новой статьи/поста?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Коллеги, правильно ли я понимаю, что WYSIWYG как раз используется для этих целей и выбирается какой-то из наиболее часто используемых?

Можете рассказать немного про это. Про конкретно как сделать много туторов/видосов, а что скрывается под капотом всего этого не могу связать в голове.

Comment: `WYSIWYG` == What You See Is What You Get. Грубо - что видишь на экране, то получишь при печати. И похрен, для чего такой редактор используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WYSIWYG - я бы рассматривал именно как вид редакторов, которые в реальном времени, при работе с текстом или другими элементами, отображали фактическое состояние, стили, оформление.

**Такие редакторы не требуют знания HTML и позволяют быстро создать необходимый и оформленный материал.**

#### **Самый простой пример - Microsoft Word**

Это и есть "визивиг" редактор, который по мере редактирования текста сохраняет "под капотом" стили, теги и другую необходимую атрибутику для сохранения визуальной стилистики. Плюс у таких редакторов есть свой набор инструментов - шрифт, его размер, цвет, вставка картинки и таблицы и много чего еще.

На просторах интернета каких душе угодно редакторов - TinyMCE, Imperavi (привел парочку примеров). Как платные так и бесплатные со своими наборами функций и возможностью самостоятельного расширения их функциональности.

P.S. Если вы интересуетесь этим вопросом как WEB разработчик или человек относящийся к этой сфере - однозначно и неизбежно стоит познакомиться и использовать WYSIWYG редактор.

Но такие редакторы не всегда нужны. Например если необходимо добавить комментарий к статье на сайте, иногда лучше использовать обычную TEXTAREA

Comment: Доступными словами, спасибо большое!
А не подскажите, хотя бы ссылку на статью какую-то, как организовать в базе данных вывод информации, которая заполняется с админки на страницах? Я как предполагаю, на каждую страницу создать по отдельной таблице и в каком-то поле (type, например, где пользователь заполняет блок преимуществ, где есть картиночка и описание, type = 'benefits') фильтровать с помощью SQL-запроса и выводить данные на страницу (надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: Здравствуйте, рад был помочь ) Подскажу, но наверно стоит уточнить какой именно результат вам нужен. Организация структуры таблицы материалов или же механизм передачи данных из WYSIWYG в базу данных. От этого сильно может измениться перечень материалов, которые можно посоветовать вам )

Comment: Да по обоим направлениям немного бы своих мыслей накидали я был бы рад, так вы уже ответили на мой вопрос. Можете просто какой-то сценарий (ситуацию) описать, был бы благодарен